# How to make a NTML request with Alamofire 4.0?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, ntlm-authentication

These are request headers:

```
    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "username": "someUserName",
        "password": "aPasswordForSomeUserName"
    ]
```

**When making a request with below code it's giving me "Garbage at the end".** However, when I checked the response with JSON parser online. It's a valid JSON.

```
Alamofire.request("http://myserver/list.svc/random", headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
    print(response)
}
```

**I also tried making a request like this**:

```
Alamofire.request("http://myserver/list.svc/random", headers: headers).responseString { response in
    print(response)
}
```

**I am getting this message in console: "401 UNAUTHORIZED"**.

What am I doing wrong? I believe, when using `responseJSON` completion block it's not complaining about `Unauthorization`, but it's complaining about bad JSON (or some garbage).

P.S. The same request works fine with Advance Rest Client (a chrome extension) and also in chrome browser.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how relevant this is to you anymore but I've got a working solution I'll post for any future reference.

So, I had two issues. The first one being that the Authorization header fell of the request when it was redirected. The second one being the NTLM-challenge from the server not being handled. The following code should be quite self explanatory I hope :) It asumes you store the username and password in variables name just that.

```
    let credentialData = "\(username):\(password)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
    let base64Credentials = credentialData.base64EncodedString(options: [])
    request.addValue("Basic \(base64Credentials)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

    let manager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
    let delegate: Alamofire.SessionDelegate = manager.delegate

    // This bit will re-add the auth headers for the redirected request
    delegate.taskWillPerformHTTPRedirection = { session, task, response, request in
        var redirectedRequest = request

        if let originalRequest = task.originalRequest, let redirectheaders = originalRequest.allHTTPHeaderFields {
            if let authorizationHeaderValue = redirectheaders["Authorization"] {
                redirectedRequest.setValue(authorizationHeaderValue, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
            }
            if let contentTypeHeaderValue = redirectheaders["Content-Type"] {
                redirectedRequest.setValue(contentTypeHeaderValue, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            }
        }

        return redirectedRequest
    }

    // This bit looks at challenges received and applies the correct credentials
    delegate.taskDidReceiveChallenge = { session, task, challenge in
        var disposition: URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition = .useCredential
        var credential: URLCredential = URLCredential()

        if (challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodNTLM) {
            disposition = URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition.useCredential
            credential = URLCredential(user: username, password: password, persistence: URLCredential.Persistence.forSession)
        }

        if (challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust) {
            disposition = URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition.useCredential
            credential = URLCredential(trust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!)
        }

        return(disposition, credential)
    }

    manager.request(request).responseData { (response) in
        // Handle response accordingly
    }
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

In **Swift4.2**

Alamofire has built in `NTLM` auth support.
You can make a request like that

```
        let user = "YOUR_USER_NAME OR EMAIL"
        let password = "YOUR_PASSWORD"
        let url = "YOUR_API_URL"
        let credential = URLCredential(user: user, password: password, persistence: .forSession)
        //These headers are optional based on your api and your server.
        //There were required for me
        let headers = ["Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                           "Content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose"]
        Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, headers: headers).authenticate(usingCredential: credential).responseJSON {
                (response) in
                switch response.result {
                case .success:
                    if let value = response.result.value {
                        print("The server response is: ", value)
                    }else{
                        print("There is error in the server response")
                    }
                case .failure (let error):
                    print("The NTLM request error is: ", error.localizedDescription)
                }

            }
```